# Sum of numbers by bill numbers in excel?

Tags: excel-formula

```
sno      sales
1        25
2        12
         11
         10
3        989
         345
         122
```

I need formula to do addition on sno wise.

Out anwser should be

```
25
33
1456
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a helper column with the following formula:

```
=IF(A2<>"",A2,C1)
```

[image]

Then from the two left columns create a Pivot Table:

[image]